# Pulling random images from resource file within the program

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple randomizer, click the button and different images appear. I've put all of my images into a resource1.resx section (68 of them) and named each as 1_png, 2_png etc.

I'm trying to randomly pull different images from the resource section but I keep getting an identifier error. This is my first project with visual studio and C# so i'm a little bit lost. Here's what I have so far.

I've tried changing the names of the files themselves, tried changing the code to accept the new images but nothing works.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                p1 = IntUtil.Random(1, 8);
                p2 = IntUtil.Random(1, 8);
                p3 = IntUtil.Random(1, 8);
                p4 = IntUtil.Random(1, 8);
            }

            if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.(p1.ToString() + "_png");

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox2.Image = Resource1.(p2.ToString() + "_png");

            if (pictureBox3.Image != null) pictureBox3.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox3.Image = Resource1.(p3.ToString() + "_png");

            if (pictureBox4.Image != null) pictureBox4.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox4.Image = Resource1.(p4.ToString() + "_png");
```

what i'm expecting to happen is when i push the button that different random images will appear in each of the 4 picture boxes.

Comment: What is "an identifier error"?  And what is this syntax?: `Resource1.()` ?  It looks like you have an errand period or forgot to include something there.

Comment: I'ld also remove the loop: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. Whatever `IntUtil.Random` returns, you don't need it to return a tenfold of it. -- Since you have 68 images, maybe it should be `p1 = IntUtil.Random(1, 69);` etc.

Comment: the resource1.() is my attempt to try and pull a random picture from the resource section and display it.

Comment: What is `Resource1`? Is it an instance of `System.Resources.ResourceManager`? If that's so, see the [ResourceManager.GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject) method. You can pass it the name of a resource, as a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Resource1.(...)` is not a valid expression. To get a value dynamically from resouce use `ResouceManager`:

```
var rm = Resource1.ResourceManager;
var i = 2;
var image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(i.ToString() + "_png");
```